# Error "property value expected css" and "at-rule or selector expected css" editing Go template in VSCode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, go-templates

I'm using Go and package `html/template`. This is my code in `mypage.tmpl`:

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
        <i class='fas fa-square companies-color' style="color: {{.Company.Color}}"></i>
</div>
```

But I get errors in VSCode:

> property value expected css(css-property value expected)

and

> at-rule or selector expected css(css-rule selector expected)

when I try `{{ }}` in style html.

[image: screen shot of VSCode error messages]

Comment: I don't use VSCode, but this looks like your editor thinks your `*.tmpl` file should be valid CSS and is complaining that it's not valid (which it isn't, it only becomes valid CSS once the template is executed). You either need a plug-in/setting that recognises Go template files (e.g. understands `{{…}}`) or turn off syntax checking for `*.tmpl` files.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I have found solution. Turn off html validate styles in setting's vscode

[image: vscode disable validate style html]

Comment: Please note that this will affect all projects opened. In case you just want to turn off this setting for a particular workspace, you should create a folder called `.vscode` on the root of your project, then a file called `settings.json` inside, and add `"html.validate.styles": true`. More info about this method can be found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: @FranVerona I think you meant `"html.validate.styles": false` since thats what the thread creator was looking for.

Comment: This solution doesn't work with PHP files

Answer (score 9):

Hi I fixed this this by installing the Django extension in VsCode

Comment: Nice Hack ! Thanks ;)

Comment: For me this is the better solution, thanks! :)

Comment: Confirmed this is working, this is much better solution but it kinda bothers me the need to install another extension that probably won't have any uses aside from removing annoying red lines on vscode.

Comment: There are several extensions. I have installed this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=batisteo.vscode-django and worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

For people using PHP Intelephense, turn off Intelephense > Diagnostics: Embedded Languages should work.

[image: Turn off Intelephense feature]