# Angular template error - property value expectedcss(css-propertyvalueexpected)

Tags: css, angular

Why do I get the error below for the below template code on the first curly bracket.
It still seems to work fine.

> property value expectedcss(css-propertyvalueexpected)

```
<div class="error-loading" style="color: {{tenant?.style.pageColorCardPage ? tenant?.style.pageColorCardPage : tenant?.style.pageColor}};">
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57352156/error-property-value-expected-css-and-at-rule-or-selector-expected-css-editi

Comment: @SujitSingh Yes that is it thanks.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57495678/10222449

Answer (score 0):

Because the css is invalid until the code is executed, at which point it becomes valid and displays correctly.

The way I have got around this is when setting a style on a row

in the template..

```
<tr *ngFor='let row of reportData$' [style]="getRowStyle(row)">
```

and in the component you can get as creative as you like...

```
getRowStyle(row: any){
  return "border: "+row.border_weight+"px solid black;";
}
```